# Why doesn't my code to expand all panes in an AjaxControlToolkit Accordion work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, firefox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using an AjaxControlToolkit Accordion with the following code to expand all AccordionPanes (I'm calling this function with an HTML anchor):

```
function expandViewAll() {
  var behavior = $get("<%= accViewIncident.ClientID %>").AccordionBehavior;
  for (var i = 0; i < behavior._panes.length; i++) {
    behavior.get_Pane(i).content.style.display = 'inline';
    behavior.get_Pane(i).content.height = behavior.get_Pane(i).content.scrollHeight;
    behavior.get_Pane(i).content.style.height = behavior.get_Pane(i).content.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
}
```

I also have a corresponding `collapseViewAll()` function.

The expand function works properly in Chrome and IE 9, but in Firefox (latest version) it doesn't; it expands all the panes, but their contents are not visible except for the pane that was selected at the time the expand link was clicked. Here's an image illustrating this:

[image: expand function broken in Firefox]

The "Consumer Information" and "Incident Information" areas should have information displayed, but they're coming up empty. No errors come up in Firebug console. Again, this works as expected in Chrome (latest) and IE 9 (I don't have a way to test in other IE versions).

I know this isn't much to go on, but does anybody know of any issues with Accordion controls in Firefox that might explain this, and even more importantly, is there a way to fix it? I'll be happy to provide more information as needed.

Comment: Check to see what CSS is being applied to the content of the panels.  It is possible that the Accordion CSS is being applied then any default CSS you have set on the content is being applied, causing it to be hidden.

Comment: I'm not setting "hidden" anywhere in my CSS, but you're right; in Chrome the Accordion content div has this CSS: `style="display: block; height: auto; overflow: auto;"`, and in Firefox the same div has this: `style="display: block; height: auto; overflow: hidden;"`. Any idea where that `overflow: hidden;` might be coming from?

Comment: That is strange and I don't have any other ideas off the top of my head outside of it being an order of operations issues.

This thread might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883985/ajax-accordion-issues-in-firefox-chrome

Comment: If you go in Firebug, and manually change the AccordionPanes to be visible, do you see the content then?  Also, what happens if you set behavior.get_Pane(i).content.style.display = 'block'; instead of inline?

Comment: Nothing happens when I change it from display='block' to display='inline'. I haven't been able to figure out how to manually set the panes to visible in Firebug. But I do see when I view the source after clicking the "Expand All" link that style="display:none;" is being put in there somehow. Problem is, I don't know where that's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the doctype set?

I.E.

```
            <!doctype html>
```

-- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Comment: I have the doctype set to xhtml 1.0 transitional (`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`).

Comment: I tried both the XHTML 1.1 and the HTML5 doctypes, and neither made any difference.

Comment: Can you try hard coding the height, temporarily?

Comment: behavior.get_Pane(i).content.height = 500;
    behavior.get_Pane(i).content.style.height = '500px';

Comment: Hard coding the height just gives me a 500px high blank space instead of the blank space being the size of the content that should be showing.

Comment: So that means there is an issue with the display property. HAve you looked at in Firebug?

Comment: Yes, it does appear to be an issue with the display property - `style=display:none` is being set somehow (but not by me).